# Intellij can't import Java Libraries to use with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Today I reinstalled Intellij on the version 2020 EAP (since I formatted my pc), and imported back my Kotlin proyects, proyects that worked well before this installation, but now I can't import none of the java libraries, I see this when adding an Java Import:

[photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1md.png)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try to change the project SDK in `File | Project Structure | Project`.

Comment: change it to what?

Comment: To JDK 11 or 8 for example